# A simple number theory question: Prove that for any natural number a and prime number p, $a^{p^{p-1}}\equiv a$ mod p.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for any natural number a and prime number p, $a^{p^{p-1}}\equiv a$ mod p.

Comment: Do you know Fermat little theorem?

Comment: And note that the $n$-th power of the function $x\mapsto x^k$ is $x\mapsto x^{k^n}$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You mean $x\mapsto x^{kn}$, right?

Comment: @Braindead: No I meant what I wrote. Check $(x^k)^k=x^{k^2}$, not $x^{2k}$. Note that $n$-th power of $f$ means $x\mapsto f^n(x)$, not $x\mapsto f(x)^n$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Okay, by $n$-th power, you mean composition $n$-times. Yeah, sorry, I should've figured from context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marc-van-Leeuwen pointed out, using Fermat's little theorem:

$$a^{p}\equiv a \text{ mod p}$$

Under the substitution $a\rightarrow a^p$, gives:

$$a^{p^2}\equiv a^p\equiv a \text{ mod p}$$

Continuing in this matter one can obtain:

$$a^{p^3}\equiv a^{p^2}\equiv a^{p}\equiv a \text{ mod p}$$

And so on, until you've substituted $a^{p}$ a total of $p-2$ times giving your desired congruence: $$a^{p^{p-1}}\equiv a \text{ mod p}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By Fermat's Little Theorem:

$$a^p=a\pmod p\implies a^{p^2}=(a^p)^p=a^p\pmod p=a\pmod p\;\ldots$$